# Development environment for C#

Tags: c#, macos

Could you introduce me a development environment you recommend for C# on Mac?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want [Mono for OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX). [Download page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html). And for an IDE, [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mac_Preview).

Comment: All hail, Novell! Mono & MonoDevelop are two of my fav. funded open source projects.

Comment: @ffffff, you might as well accept the answer - you ain't gettin 'nother one.

Comment: Yes Mono is the only solution but MonoDevelop is not as good as Visual Studio or Sharp Develop so it will be quite annoying to develop code with very less tools, you might need to learn tutorials to get hang of the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

I migrated some months ago from windows to mac.. it's been a long while since the last time i logged into windows, and I was a C# freak.. so back on mac i tried using Mono, and.. i was really dissapointed because it's not like in Windows: you have a weak IDE to work with and it seems so.. poor! Then i decided to make the big step and switch to objective-c and Cocoa! And now i'm happy again as i was on windows. So, my point here is if you wanna keep going with C#, stick to the windows platform.. but if you want to develop mac apps, try moving to objective-c and Cocoa!

Comment: You can try WINE + SharpDevelop on Mac

Comment: What if you have a hackintosh where virtualization isn't supported ?

Comment: @Woofy ... if you have a blog entry somewhere on the migration from C#/.NET to Objective-C/Cocoa ... please let me know because I really can't seem to like Objective-C but am willing to give it another chance

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [WINE](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) thats sort of emulator for windows programs on Mac/Linux and you can try installing .net and SharpDevelop tools, and use mono to create output, the benefit is you will get little rich tools to do your development.

Comment: Actually (and really unrelated) but WINE stands for Wine Is Not an Emulator... Just for future reference :D

Comment: Thats why I wrote that its sort of emulator, it isnt emulator.

Answer (score 0):

- TextWrangler + Mono
- Parallels + UltraEdit + command-line compilation
- Parallels + Visual Studio

I'm downloading MonoDevelop now, haven't tried it in awhile.

Answer (score 0):

I use [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) to run Visual Studio in a Windows virtual machine.  I'd only recommend this if you've got a fast Intel processor with at least 4GB of ram.

Fusion also offers a "Unity" mode so that Visual Studio would look like it's being run as a native Mac application.  A great concept, but in practice it uses way too much RAM and processor.

Otherwise you could use [boot camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) to run Visual Studio in Windows.  This gives you the full strength of your hardware resources but you have to boot to use it.